# No route matches [GET] /places/photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails application and have recently added an "add photo" option.  However, when I click the button I'm presented with a

> no route matches [GET]" error message.

I've checked the other answers here and the information doesn't seem to help on my end.

Here's the code for my routes.rb file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'places#index'

  resources :places do
    resources :comments, only: :create
    resources :photos, only: :create
    end
    resources :users, only: :show
end
```

Comment: You want to list out photos but why do you want to limit only `create` action on your routes?

Comment: @Tai I don't want to limit it only to create.  Basically, if the user is logged in, then they should be able to add or delete a photo.  This was a self-guided lesson in a course that I'm taking, but it's become quite tangled up.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`resources :photos, only: :create` will match the route: POST `/places/:id/photos`, not GET `/places/photos`

You can modify a bit as below:

```
resources :places do
  resources :comments, only: :create
  resources :photos, only: :create
  collection do
    resources :photos, only: :index
  end
end
```

You can read more at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I updated my routes file, however I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: @JustinCefai Could you help show the output of command: `bundle exec rails routes` if you ran rails 5 or `bundle exec rake routes` for rails version < 5 (list all routers available) after modified.

Comment: root GET    /                                    places#index
          place_comments POST   /places/:place_id/comments(.:format) comments#create
            place_photos POST   /places/:place_id/photos(.:format)   photos#create
                  photos GET    /places/photos(.:format)             photos#index
                  places GET    /places(.:format)                    places#index
                         POST   /places(.:format)                    places#create

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure there's a better way to send that

Comment: @JustinCefai, You can edit your post and at the bottom you can add your new code, then ask whomever to refer to the bottom of your question.  I will just say this: your routes are waaaay too complex for a beginner.  I don't even think you should use `resources`: as a beginner.  Instead, you should manually add all the routes you need for awhile before using the `resources:` shortcut.  If you haven't seen it already, check out the book "Ruby on Rails Tutorial", which is available for free online: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-rails_routes

Comment: Thanks @7stud.  This is for a bootcamp, and judging by the curriculum so far I think they just throw you in the deep end and let you figure out how to swim.  I'm going to keep jamming until it makes sense :)

Comment: @JustinCefai, Okay, good luck.  Do you know about `bin/rake routes`?  It will show you all the routes created by your routes.rb file.

Comment: @7stud I do, but I'm still a bit confused as to how to read the output.

Comment: @JustinCefai I saw your output included: `photos GET /places/photos(.:format) photos#index` . It means we had this route GET `/places/photos` and the controller/method resolve it are `photos_controller` and `def index` and It should work. if you got another errors, please help detail.

Comment: @PhanViệt I tried adding def index to my photos controller and am still getting the same error message even after restarting my server.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would really be to just add a route for your action without using `resources`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  get 'route-name-you-want' => 'your_controller#your_action'
end
```